# How to write a regex that includes `abc` or `bcd` but not `diy` in one line

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I just write that:

`if $_ =~ /abc|bcd/ && $_ !~ /diy/`

How to write that in one regexp. Both in `perl` or `grep` are ok. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible with regex using some lookahead assertions

```
$i =~ /^(?=.*(?:abc|bcd))(?!.*diy)/
```

`(?=.*(?:abc|bcd))` will be true if there is one of the parts in there you want

`(?!.*diy)` will fail if the string you don't want is in there

But I think your solution is more clear.

Comment: will one regexp faster than two regexps in this case?

Comment: @madper sorry, but I think every answer about performance would be a wild guess in this case. If you do this `if` very (very, very) often then just do a benchmark. If you do this from time to time, use what you like better.

Answer (score 3):

The lookahead/behind suggested in another answer doesn't work for this problem.  And to use lookbehind, you'd need variable length lookbehind, which perl does not support.

```
/^(?!.*?diy).*?(?:abc|bcd)/s
```

Another approach:

```
/^(?:(?!diy).)*(?:abc|bcd(?!iy))(?:(?!diy).)*\z/s
```

In either case, factoring the bc out of the | may produce a more efficient regex.

Answer (score 2):

Negating a sequence of characters is usually a pain in regex. You'd have to use look-ahead assertions.

If you were testing for contiguous sequences, you could try to do it with look-aheads and look-behinds, something like `(?<!diy)(abc|bcd)(?!diy)`, but that will probably be ambiguous.

I would leave the test just like yours, only losing the default variable:

```
if /(abc|bcd)/ and not /diy/
```

Clear and clean. :)

Comment: You'd have to use lookahead operators if you don't have the support in the regex; but negating is definitely within the realm of a finite automaton. If you were to build tables, there would be many states, but it's possible without; for example by algebra. Instead of following arrows from bubble to bubble, you can perform derivations from regex formula to regex formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'now I know my abcs' | txr -c '@/.*(abc|bcd).*&~.*diy.*/' -

$ echo 'no match' | txr -c '@/.*(abc|bcd).*&~.*diy.*/' -
false

$ echo 'Kaz wanted better regex, so he did the diy thing, starting from abc' | txr -c '@/.*(abc|bcd).*&~.*diy.*/' -
false
```

`false` is accompanied by a failed termination status, and indicates no match. No output means match.

We use `.*`'s because the match is anchored. `@/RE/` by itself on a line means that the line has to match the regex; i.e. when we feed that line to the regex machine, from beginning to end, the machine is an acceptance state.

When you have regexes like this, having the search-semantics in the regex is bad. I.e. if `foo` actually means `.*(foo).*` (match `foo` anywhere in the text), that doesn't work very well for `foo&~bar` because `.*(foo&~bar).*` does not mean the same thing as `.*foo.*&~.*bar.*`. The former means "match any string which has a substring that matches `foo&~bar`." But that's an impossible match; no string can be `foo` and `bar` at the same time. It's an empty intersection. But the latter means "match a string that contains `foo` somewhere in it, but does not contain `bar` anywhere." Now you're in business.

Comment: I think you can get `grep` which does this sort of thing from AT&T research.

Comment: What is `txr` and where does it come from?  It doesn't seem to be available as a standard tool (ports or packages) on any of my FreeBSD or Linux machines.

Comment: It's new (< 3 years). The day when it's available like that hasn't arrived. For now, people build from sources: http://www.nongnu.org/txr.

Comment: Very interesting.  I may added it to the FreeBSD ports tree, if you don't object.

Comment: I would be pleased; and please don't be shy to report even the slightest porting difficulties.